# How to open file stored in variable using File.Open in ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, console

I want to open file and read it that I pass from console.
Like

```
filename = gets()
File.open(filename,'r') do |file|
```

but getting error like following on console:

```
test.rb:7:in `initialize': Invalid argument - myfile (Errno::EINVAL)
        from test.rb:7:in `open'
        from test.rb:7
```

Is it possible to read file having filename taken from console and perform `do |file| ..end` in ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String you read from the STDIN has a trailing `\n`. Get rid of it.

```
filename = gets().chomp
```